# How do i get the li text alone not inner HTML too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a html like this:

```
   <ul id="NameList">
        <li><span>Name1<span>100</span></span></li>
        <li><span>Name2<span>200</span></span></li>
        <li><span>Name3<span>300</span></span></li>
    </ul>
```

I need to convert html to json objects

So i tried this method

```
 var items = [];

        $('ul#NameList').children().each(function () {
            var data1, data2;
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.children().each(function () {
                data1 = $(this).html();
                $child1 = $(this);
                $child1.children().each(function () {
                data2 = $(this).html();
                });
            });
            var item = { data1: data1, data2: data2 };
            items.push(item);
        });
```

In the output `data1` have the value like `Name1<span>100</span>`

but i need `Name1` alone, not the inner Html `<span>100</span>`

I need the output like this:

```
  items = [{data1:'Name1',data2:'100'},{data1:'Name2',data2:'200'},{data1:'Name3',data2:'300'}];
```

But now i m getting my output like this:

```
items = [{data1:'Name1<span>100</span>',data2:'100'},{data1:'Name2<span>200</span>',data2:'200'},{data1:'Name3<span>300</span>',data2:'300'}];
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this too

`data1 = $(this).text();`

But its giving the output like this:

```
items = [{data1:'Name1100',data2:'100'},{data1:'Name2200',data2:'200'},{data1:'Name3300',data2:'300'}];
```

It takes the innerhtml's text too !!

Can any one help to solve this ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: You have some nasty tag soup to deal with: nesting 2 spans means that the outer span's `textContent` consists of both its own and the child nodes text content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:-
  replace

```
data1 = $(this).html();
data2 = $(this).html();
```

with

```
 data1 = $(this).text().replace($(this).find('span:first').text(),'');
 data2 = $(this).text();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LLgerjgb/)

Answer (score 3):

replace:

```
data1 = $(this).html();
...
data2 = $(this).html();
```

with

```
data1 = $(this).text().replace($(this).find('span:first').text(),'');
...
data2 = $(this).text();
```

it will return only text without html tags.

Comment: Using `this.textContent` (ie vanillaJS, not jQ) works just fine, too and is more performant

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = [];

        $('ul#NameList').children().each(function () {
            var data1, data2;
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.children().each(function () {
                data1 = $(this).html();
                data1 = data1.find("span").remove();
                $child1 = $(this);
                $child1.children().each(function () {
                data2 = $(this).html();
                });
            });
            var item = { data1: data1, data2: data2 };
            items.push(item);
        });
```

Comment: Good thinking Mouhamad , but its not working for me, getting error in `find`

Comment: if data1 = data1.find("span").remove(); is not working, so try: data1 = $(this).find("span").remove();